# Mount USB floppy drive always at same mount point

Tags: usb, mount, fstab, drive, floppy

I'd like to mount my USB floppy at the same mount point regardless of the disk.

The problem is that adding a line to `/etc/fstab` with the UUID doesn't work. I thought the UUID belonged to the USB floppy drive, but, apparently, it changes with each floppy disk.

Every time I put a floppy in, it mounts it at `/media/whatever-UIID`, but I want it to always mount at `/media/floppy`, regardless of the disk.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You haven't provided OS & release details; but why not use `/dev/fd0`  (floppy drive 0; note: I'm not on a box with a floppy; though I don't recall needing to do anything last time I did testing with floppies in *focal* (2020) cycle)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't use /dev/fd0 because this is not a floppy drive connected to a floppy controlled card. I used /dev/fd0 or fd1 in my old 486, and it always mounted at /mnt/floppy[10]. However, this is a USB drive and uses /dev/sd*

Comment: You still haven't provided any OS & release details... if using a desktop what desktop that is etc..   fyi:  I *tested* with USB-connected floppy drives too, and don't recall any differences, though I was looking for a specific issue, and how the floppy drive is connected maybe impacted by the box firmware  (ie. your results maybe different to the 3-5 machines I tested a bug fix on)

Comment: Linux acer 4.4.0-210-generic #242-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 09:57:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Laptop: Acer TavelMate B
But I want this to work on as many systems as possible.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: You still haven't provided your OS & release details; however that kernel is the GA kernel for 16.04 & thus off-topic, or the HWE kernel for 14.04 & likewise still off-topic.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry for having inconvenienced you. Let me rephrase the question: How do I do the same thing I asked but on the latest release of Ubuntu, no matter what date you read this? Thanks.

Comment: FYI:  @vanadium's response makes sense... I can't see it being an issue with old DOS either (I use PC-DOS myself but same thing really).   In my testing PC-DOS anyway doesn't use the UUID on the floppies except for printing when you do a `dir`, `chkdsk` or like command (ie. it's only printed and never evaluated)

Comment: Don't use the UUID but use `/dev/fd0` as mount device. Like `/dev/fd0 /media/floppy/ auto noauto 0 0` in your `fstab`.

Answer (score 0):

lsusb

(idVendor:idProduct)

determine usb-floppy and add udev rule for static symbolic link
e.g
udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/bus/usb/002/004

/etc/udev/rules.d/60-usb-floppy-disk.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0000",
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", \
SYMLINK+="ufd0"
```

reload and retrigger udev rules

sudo sh -c "udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger"

sudo mkdir -v /media/floppy

/etc/fstab

/dev/ufd0 /media/floppy ext2,msdos rw,user,noauto 0 0